# render bengali(and possibly other indic) font in vim

Tags: vim, fonts, render, indic

I am trying to write in bengali(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_alphabet)
using gvim. The font rendering is not correct.
I have tried gedit, and rendering is correct there.
To compare, see [this image](http://imagebin.org/261702) for gedit and [this image](http://imagebin.org/261703) for gvim (all the non-english is actually bengaly, see the difference in eg line number 590)

and if that helps:

```
$vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May 14 2013 13:17:57)
Included patches: 1-415, 417-944
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax          
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "/etc/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim73"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/harfbuzz   -I/usr/local/include  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall  -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -Wl,-z,relro  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lSM -lICE  -lm -lnsl  -lselinux  -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -fstack-protector  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
```

Comment: What font do you use in both programs? What other font-related settings do you have in your `~/.vimrc`? Did you try anything after reading `:h guifont`, `:h guifontset` and `:h guifontwide`? If so what worked? What didn't?

Answer (score 4):

You're using a fairly recent GVIM build, that's good! I remember some old discussions on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php) around this topic (e.g. [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/eCX4wgLvfbw/bIpmoXOaMlsJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/JuhCw61L1ls/JT9Hw-xn6KoJ)), so it looks like Vim has some known deficiencies with displaying Indic scripts.

You should check on the vim_dev mailing list for a status update and to find other people with similar interests.

Comment: I also face in problem to write Bengali in vim. I will use LaTeX Bengali font for my document. But as my text editor don't support Bengali, so I can't write my document using the LaTeX Bengali font.